# When increasing the height of the screen, the child block must go beyond the parent

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a page. The location of the blocks is shown in the pictures below.
[image]

The red container is stretched to full screen. The gray container has a height of `600px`.

When the height of the crane increases, I want the green block to go beyond the parent, as shown in the figure below.

[image]

How can this be realized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved by giving the red container a width, e.g. `width: 50%;` and the green container a fixed width, that's bigger, e.g. `width: 100vw;`

**However**, this is not recommendable as this can lead to numerous problems, not to mention that it is tremendously ugly.

What is the issue with dropping the green container out of the red one and using `display: flex;` to align it beautifully?

Comment: I decided to use a negative indent